# Deleting cookie of the instagram authorization page in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, instagram

In my rails application i am using oauth to get access to the user's profile data. The thing is when the instagram's authorization log-in page pops up, the user has to enter his log-in details, a cookie gets saved in my machine. Is there any way to DELETE this cookie(obviously not manually)? I am asking this because when the oauth page is called again, this cookie saved in my browser automatically signs in the user.  This has become a nuisance for my project. I don't want this to happen, i want the same log-in page to be displayed again.

Comment: Why do you not want the automated sign in once a user has already signed in? Automatic sign in is expected/useful behaviour and making things harder for your users only a negative user experience, but there might be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: There should be some kind of a "logout" url, which you can visit (as the user) and it will deletes their cookies. e.g. Twitter has [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/end_session)

Comment: The login page wont be shown to the user everytime. Normally his information will be fetched from the access token i have in my DB. In case of an access token expiry he'll have to relogin(because instagram has no refresh token). The problem is when the user clicks on the link to relogin, the previously stored instagram cookie starts off the authorization automatically. I really want to get rid of this cookie.

Comment: I checked the API. There is no logout in instagram!!!. Just read somewhere that it is going to come soon. Is there no other way to get rid of this cookie without manually deleting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are wanting to log the user out of instagram as well as your application.  In order to do that you can send their browser to https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/.  I've seen it used as a image URL or loaded in a zero size iframe.  I suspect the second is the better option.

That way it will required the instagram login again the second time, but won't require them to reauthorize your application.